# Can I do the speed run achievements after I finish the act?

Tags: achievements, diablo-iii

There are 4 achievements for speed runs, one for each act, and another for completing all of them. Will I be able to do those runs after I finish the game with a developed character and how, or do they have to be done on the first trial of a certain difficulty?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, I took the time to try it out, and just finished it (it was pretty close though, even though I'm already Level 30, I finished 5 minutes before the end of the timer).

You can in fact do it with a developed character by going back to the quest via the character screen.

Proof: [image]

By the way: The same thing counts for all other achievements. For example, there is one to kill the Skeleton King within 30 seconds, which I picked up along the way, too.

Comment: Congratulation on the achievement.